# UI elements periodically flickering

Tags: windows-10

Since upgrading to Windows 10, there's a weird issue that randomly happens anywhere between every minute, to ever hour or more.

The taskbar, and certain UI elements in other windows flicker. They just switch between blank, and what they should be, maybe 5-6 times a second, only for a second or so, then everything is back to normal.

It's not all UI elements, Chrome/Firefox seem to be fine, but Windows Explorer is effected, and HeidiSQL (program we use to manage our dev database).

I've seen posts with a *similar* issue, where after a while the screen flickers and Windows becomes completely unusable afterwards.

Has anybody else had this issue and managed to solve it, or have any idea what I could try to fix it?

Spec is:

> Window 10 Home 64-bit (Build 10586)
>   8GB of RAM
>   i5 3.1GHz Quad Core
>   NVIDIA GeForce GT 635

If you need any other details just ask.

Comment: Bug is confirmed, but no solution yet: http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=19141

Comment: For a while not this issue has disappeared, I guess after some Windows update, but it's interesting that it's still an issue for some people.

Comment: I have this issue, but nothing to do with HeidiSQL. Any idea what else causes it?